# configure automatic Hy REPL imports

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, hy

I've been absolutely loving the Hy REPL. However it would speed up my workflow immensely if I could have a set of default imports at startup. Clojure has a way of configuring startup imports via leiningen config. Currently I load the repl this way:

```
path/bin/hy --repl-output-fn=hy.contrib.hy-repr.hy-repr
```

Similarly is there a way I can reset all imported modules from the REPL namespace without having to restart the REPL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper initialization scripts are [not yet implemented](https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/1832). In the meantime, you can do things like

```
hy -i '(import math re pandas)'
```

or

```
hy -i '(import [my-init-package [*]])'
```

to run some code of your choice before starting the REPL.